# multiple tailf commands?

Tags: linux

How to use multiple tailf command in linux? Have tried so many but unfortunately nothing worked.

```
[admin.ar@IRISCORE home]$ cd iris
[admin.ar@IRISCORE iris]$ cd logs
[admin.ar@IRISCORE logs]$ tailf fundamoxlo_verbose.o0822(Log file,Month,Date)
                          tailf concenisoxli_verbose.o0822(Log file,Month,Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).  It follows multiple log files in one window.

Answer (score 0):

`tailf` accepts one file as the argument.
So, no, it's not possible like that.

You can use something like `tail -f foo* bar*`